# Django admin raw_id_fields table display

Tags: django, django-admin

Django raw_id_fields don't display tables the way I expect, am I doing something wrong?   I'm trying to use a raw_id_fields widget to edit a ForeignKey field as follows:

```
#models.py
class OrderLine(models.Model):
    product = ForeignKey('SternProduct')

class SternProduct(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self): return self.product_num
    product_num = models.CharField(max_length=255)

#admin.py
#import and register stuff  
class OrderLineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    raw_id_fields=('product')
```

I get the little textbox and magnifier widget as expected, but clicking the magnifier gives me this:
*flickr.com/photos/28928816@N00/5244376512/sizes/o/in/photostream/*
(sorry, can't post more than one hyperlink apparently)

I thought I would get something closer to the changelist page c/w columns, filters and search fields.  In fact, that's apparently [what others get](http://www.thecssdiv.co.uk/2008/09/22/django-raw-id-fields-explained-basically/).

Any thoughts about how to enable the more featureful widget?

Comment: Note that this: ('product')  is not a tuple, it`s a string! To create a tuple you need to use ('product',) or just 'product',

Answer (score 9):

Ah, OK, this should have been obvious, but it isn't explained in the Django docs.  The list that appears in the raw_id_fields popup uses the same options as the admin object for the referenced model.  So in my example, to get a nice looking popup I needed to create a SternProductAdmin object as follows:

```
class SternProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__', 'drawing_number', 'drawing_revision',)
    list_filter = ('drawing_number',)
    search_fields = ('drawing_number',)
    actions = None
```

Hopefully this will help others in the future.